# Is "delegable" a word?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, is-it-a-word

Wiktionary [defines](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delegatable) *delegetable* as *capable of being delegated*, which seems correct to the French speaking that I am. However, the same Wiktionary also [defines](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delegable) *delegable* as *that can be delegated*.

Does *delegable* exist? Is it a synonym for *delegatable*? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: I'm a long-time Wiktionary editor and I advise you to take everything there with a grain of salt like any other wiki.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=delegable%2Cdelegatable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdelegable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdelegatable%3B%2Cc0) strongly prefers *delegable* notably in legal texts though *delegetable* is not unknown especially in cryptography

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary*, *Oxford English Dictionary*, and dictionary.com reports *delegable* as derivative word of *delegate*; none of them reports *delegetable* as English word.

Comment: So actually, _delegatable_ is not a word, while _delegable_ is the correct adjective. Thanks!

Comment: Proper and correct it may be, but it still sounds more descriptive of a table from Ikea than a task one can hand off to somebody else.

Comment: The adoption of "delegable" as the correct word by so called dictionary authorities is flawed imho. "Delegatable" conveys it's meaning very easily - it can be seen in it's spelling and it's meaning can be heard in it's sound. Language is about communicating. Most likely, usage of whichever of the 2 words above will ultimately determine which word wins out. Not what the dictionary authority says.

Comment: Dictionaries are supposed to say which words are used, not which words should be used. I didn't cite the dictionary for its authority, but because reports which word is used at the time the dictionary is read (n this case, 10 years ago).